# Stirling Numbers Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

The signless Stirling number of the first kind $\text{c(n,k)}$ is the sum of all products of $\text{(n-k)}$ integers from the range $\{1,2,...,\text{n-1}\}$, of which there are
$ \binom{n-k} {k-1} $ such products.
Verify that $\text{c}(6,2) = (1\times2\times3\times4)+(1\times2\times3\times5)+(1\times2\times4\times5)+(1\times3\times4\times5)+(2\times3\times4\times5) = 274$

Have this as a possible exam question but cannot figure it out. Any help please

Comment: What's the question? Surely you can verify the arithmetic yourself.

Comment: Yeah of course but its showing that c has 6 orbits that are represented as so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you simply need to verify that ${6\brack 2}=274$, where $6\brack 2$ is the (unsigned) Stirling number of the first kind. How you’re to do this depends on how you’ve defined the Stirling numbers of the first kind. The usual definition is that $n\brack k$ is the number of permutations of $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$ with exactly $k$ disjoint cycles, so that’s the one that I’ll use.

$6\brack 2$ is then the number of permutations of $[6]=\{1,\dots,6\}$ having exactly $2$ disjoint cycles. Suppose that the cycle containing $1$ is a $k$-cycle, where of course $1\le k\le 5$. There are $\binom5{k-1}$ ways to choose the other $k-1$ members of the cycle, and there are then $(k-1)!$ ways to permute them, so there are

$$\binom5{k-1}(k-1)!=\frac{5!}{(6-k)!}$$

ways to choose the cycle containing $1$. The $6-k$ members of the other cycle are then completely determined, and there are $(5-k)!$ cyclically distinct orders for them. Thus, the number of permutations of $[6]$ with exactly $2$ cycles in which the cycle containing $1$ is a $k$-cycle is

$$\frac{5!}{(6-k)!}\cdot(5-k)!=\frac{5!}{6-k}\;,$$

and

$${6\brack 2}=\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{5!}{6-k}=\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{5!}k\;.$$

You can simply evaluate the sum, or you can recognize that it actually **is** the sum that you calculated in the question.